Can I use TWFE DiD with staggered treatment adoption?
Can I use TWFE DiD with staggered treatment adoption to estimate the effects of droughts and floods on the unemployment rate? I'm examining several countries in Africa and analyzing 2-66 floods and droughts each year between 2005 and 2020. I designated the treated countries as those above the 90th percentile and untreated countries as those below the 90th percentile. I found parallel trends in the average unemployment rate at the national level for countries above and below the 90th percentile.

Welcome. Do droughts and floods affect the employment rate in the same way, or will you assess their effects separately? And why the 90th percentile? What does this mean? Above (below) the 90th percentile in what exactly?

And how is your question any different than what is posted here?

Hi, the effects will be assessed separately. Countries in the above the 90th percentile means that they were most affected by droughts or floods, thats the treatment group. Countries in the below the 90th percentile means that they were least affected by droughts or floods, thats the control group. However, I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly here or not..

I have a treatment variable/indicator that is called drought occurrence and flood occurrence (1 if flooding/drought occurred a specific year for a specific country, and 0 if it did not occur). Should I use it to create a variable with all the treated and separate one for control?

That answer is not related to what I want to work with. My study have variation in treatment timing and assumes heterogenous treatment effects. Also, I want to use TWFE DiD with staggered adoption because it allows for unit-specific treatment effects and explicitly considers variations in treatment timing. 2-S DiD rewuires homogenous effects..which I dont't have and my stuff is staggered. So, I need help with defining my control and treatment variable for this.
